# Sheaves and bundle morphisms

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, sheaf-theory, vector-bundles

I'm currently trying to reunderstand differential geometry using shaves. Let $f:(E_1,M,\pi_1)\rightarrow (E_2,M,\pi_2)$ be a $\mathcal{C}^{k}$ vector bundle morphism, where $M, E_1$ and $E_2$ are a $\mathcal{C}^{k}$ Hausdorff second countable manifolds. Consider the presheaf of modules of sections $\mathcal{F}^{k}(U):=\{s:U\subset M\rightarrow \operatorname{Im}(f)\subset E_2:\pi_2\circ s=Id_{U}\textrm{ and }s\textrm{ is } \mathcal{C}^{k}\textrm{ differentiable}\}$. Is this presheaf a sheaf?

Books and other sources are also welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't $\operatorname{Id}_U$ be $\pi_1$, as $\pi_2\circ s$ is a map $E_1\supset U\rightarrow M$?

Comment: No, $U$ is in $M$, not in $E_1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check that it satisfies the [locality and gluing properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheaf_(mathematics)#Sheaves), which I think is a mere computation:

(*Locality*) Suppose $U$ is an open set, $\{U_i\}_{i\in I}$ is an open cover of U $U$, and $s,t \in \mathcal{F}(U)$ are sections. If $s|_{U_i}=t|_{U_i}$ for all $i\in I$, then $s=t$. If not, i.e, if there exists $x$ such that $s(x)\neq t(x)$ for $x\in U_{i_0}\subset U$ then $s|_{U_{i_0}}(x)\neq t|_{U_{i_0}}(x)$, which is a contradiction.

(*Gluing*) Suppose $U$ is an open set, $\{U_i\}_{i\in I}$ is an open cover of $U$, and $\{s_i\in \mathcal{F}(U_i)\}$ is a family of sections. Suppose all pairs of sections agree on the overlap of their domains, that is, if $s_i|_{U_{ij}}=s_j|_{U_{ij}}$ for all $i,j\in I$.

You can define $s:U\to E_2$ by
$$
s(x)=s_i(x) \text{ for } x\in U_i.
$$
It is well defined, since if $x\in U_{ij}$ then $s_i(x)=s_j(x)$.

It is trivial to check that $s\in \mathcal{F}(U)$, so you have that there exists a section $s\in \mathcal{F}(U)$ such that $s|_{U_i}=s_i$ for all $i\in I$, as required.

---

In general, vector bundles are locally free sheaves. The kernel and image of vector bundle morphisms are not vector bundles (unless they are constant rank morphisms) but they are, at least, sheaves. Those sheaves are therefore not necessarily locally free ones but coherent sheaves. Coherent sheaves constitute the class of sheaves such that their image and kernel are still sheaves of the same class. You can understand them as a generalization of vector bundles.

I studied this stuff so many years ago, I hope I am not missing something...

Comment: Sorry, just to be sure, image and kernel are coherent sheaves without need to considerate their sheafification, in other words they are presheaves equal to their sheafification, aren't they?

Comment: And about the locality and gluing properties: it seems that thanks to partitions of unity of smooth manifolds every presheaf is a sheaf. Am I correct? Thank you for you time.

Comment: I have edited de answer for completeness. Respect to you comments: 1. In the introduction of [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_sheaf) it is said "they are closed under operations such as taking kernels, images, and cokernels", so I think the answer is yes. 2. In your specific example there is no need of partition of unity (to my knowledge). I don't know if your statement is too general, maybe you have to create another question... As I said, I studied this thing 14 years ago, so I only have intuitions, and I may be forgetting some technicalities.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias por los detalles colega! Me ha sido muy útil. Ya en inglés por si alguien lo quiere leer: the statement "every presheaf of a smooth manifold is a sheaf thanks to partitions of unity" is false (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheaf_(mathematics)#Sheaves_on_manifolds), but every sheaf of modules (over the ring of differentiable functions of the given manifold) is soft and hence it has vanishing cohomology (Torsten Wedhorn - Manifolds, Sheaves, and Cohomology).